# How To learn Magento 2 ?and where i can find real resources that truly help me understand modules development?

Tags: magento2, learn-magento

I have been learning `Magento 2` for over a month now from free and paid resources and still need a lot to learn to build real modules that solve real problems for the company I am working in, could you point me to resources that make me learn how to understand core modules code so I can build modules like them,

I tried to learn from tutorials and courses free and paid but didn't reach the point that I can understand some of the code of core modules to build feature-rich Magento modules like what I can find on Magento marketplace website because most of the courses and tutorials don't fully explain the code
 and pls don't tell me to learn from `u.magento`, its courses are very expensive

Thanks in advance for any answer

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40820/advanced-level-learning-for-magento?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

**Official documentation**

---

- **[Magento 2 Developer Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/)**: suitable for backend developers, frontend developers, designers and system administrators
- **[Code samples](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples)**: sample modules demonstrating how to code extensions according to best practices.

---

**Blogs, articles and videos**

---

- **[Alan Storm's Blog](https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/)** A place to get tutorial on Magento 2 with all the concepts explained in detail.
- Vinai Kopp's **[Mage2 TV](https://www.mage2.tv/content/)** can be used for training or to look up
  specific topics as a reference.
- **[Rakesh Jesadiya's Blog](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/)** 2X Magento Master 2018, 2019
- **[Magento Forums](https://community.magento.com/)**
- **[Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/)**
- **[Magestore](https://blog.magestore.com/)**
- **[Amasty Magento Blog](https://blog.amasty.com/)**
- **[Atwix Blog](https://www.atwix.com/blog/)**
- **[Inchoo Blog](http://inchoo.net/blog/)**

Answer (score 1):

Learn the basics of Magento from **Magento Developer Documentation**. Try to develop modules of different concepts. So when you try to work in realtime you will get a lot of questions which you can solve it by generally surfing through the internet and StackOverflow. There are no documents which could help you to learn everything. You can learn the basics from Magento developer documentation which gives you an idea of modules and themes. Also, try exploring various questions arisen in StackOverflow so that we can learn more in each question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Magento SE @mahmudy-91.

First thing, to learn Magento 2.x you don't need to learn magento 1.x.

To learn Magento 2.x, some of the best places are:

- [Magento's official website](http://devdocs.magento.com) (here you can find content for all)
- [Ashsmith blog](https://www.ashsmith.io)

Apart from these, have an eye at [Magento2 stack exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2)

Some more helpful links are:
http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2

http://mageclass.com/magento2-tutorials/

http://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/

http://www.sessiondigital.com/blog/category/magento-2/

[Rakesh Jesadiya's Blog](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/)

[Magento Forum](https://community.magento.com/)

[Amit Bera's Blog](https://www.amitbera.com/)

Last, but not the least, [here](https://github.com/aleron75/mageres) you can find the complete list of resources from where you can learn about Magento 2.